# How can I fix kernel problems with pyttsx3 in MAC?

Tags: python-3.x, pyttsx3

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLi2M.png)I'm seeking your assistance with a problem I'm encountering while working with speech-to-text libraries, specifically gTTS and pyttsx3. The latter is giving me execution issues, and I'm unable to make the function work properly. It's indicating kernel problems, and I've tried various solutions such as restarting the kernel, reinstalling packages, and creating a new environment.

I'm wondering if anyone has come across this issue on a Mac before. Thank you in advance for your help.

Regards.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMqFD.png)

It's indicating kernel problems, and I've tried various solutions such as updating packages and dependencies, defining paths, uninstalling and reinstalling, and ensuring that everything is properly installed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.